# Itext How to set both UTF encoding and Font to a Paragraph

Tags: itext

I want to set a font to a text that is in cyrillic.I successfully convert the text to cyrilic, but i cannot set a Font to the same text.

```
    File fontFile = new File("arialuni.ttf");
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
    document.open();
    writer.getAcroForm().setNeedAppearances(true);
    Font boldFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD);
    Font normalFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.ITALIC);
    BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont(fontFile.getAbsolutePath(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    FontSelector fs = new FontSelector();
    fs.addFont(new Font(unicode));
    addContent(document,article.getTitle(),fs,boldFont);

private static void addContent(Document document,String paragraph,FontSelector fs,Font font) throws DocumentException {
        Phrase phrase = fs.process(paragraph);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(phrase.toString(),font);
        document.add(p);
}
```

Comment: Why do you in `addContent` try to apply both a `FontSelector` and a `Font`? Either you let a selector select a font or you do it explicitly yourself...

Answer (score 3):

As @mkl indicates in the comments, you are mixing `FontSelector` functionality that gives you a `Phrase` that could use the appropriate unicode fonts (fonts with `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H` as encoding parameter), with creating a `Paragraph` with a simple font (`Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN`).

When you do `fs.process(paragraph)`, you get a `Phrase` in which every `Chunk` has the correct font, but when you do `phrase.toString()`, you throw away all those fonts, and you replace them with `Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN`. That doesn't make any sense.

Why don't you replace this:

```
Phrase phrase = fs.process(paragraph);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(phrase.toString(),font);
document.add(p);
```

with:

```
document.add(fs.process(paragraph));
```

Why does your `addContent()` method need a `Font` as parameter? Also, if you really need a `Paragraph` object you can also do this:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.add(fs.process(paragraph));
document.add(p);
```

Or even:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(fs.process(paragraph));
document.add(p);
```

As long as you don't replace the correct fonts with the incorrect fonts by "flattening" the `Phrase` to a `String`, you're probably OK.

Note that you probably even don't need the `FontSelector`. There's nothing wrong with doing this:

```
BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont(
    fontFile.getAbsolutePath(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(unicode, 12);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(paragraph, font);
```

It seems to me that you are making things unnecessary complex.

Comment: Normally, when an answer solves the problem, the answer is accepted. Please check the checkmark on the left next to the score (that score is 0 for the moment).